# BaseActivity object is null and onAttach method doesn't work in BaseFragment

Tags: android, object, null, crash, radix

In menu fragment extends base fragment

```
public class MenuFragment extends BaseFragment{
```

and onattach methot doesn't work in basefragment

```
 private BaseActivity mActivity ;

        @Override
        public void  onAttach(Context context){
            super.onAttach(context);

            if(context instanceof BaseActivity){
                BaseActivity activity =(BaseActivity) context;
                this.mActivity=activity;
                activity.onFragmentAttached();
            }
        }
```

why mActivity is null?

Comment: Do check your context instance, its probably different not BaseAcrivity. YOu can check using debugging your application. Also do check xml file what is define in  `tools.context` of `menu_fragment`.

Comment: Where are you seeing that `mActivity` is null? Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @MangeshSambare thank u for your comment. yes I checked but it's not about this.  Reason is BaseActivity not extends to MainActivity :)

Comment: @MikeM. thank u for your comment. I  solved. Reason is BaseActivity not extends to MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Problem's reason is BaseActivity didn't extend to MainActivity.